# First finishing project: Attic or Basement for office/studio?

Tags: hvac, insulation, heating, air-conditioning

First time homeowner here, 100 year-old brick bungalo in Chicago where we have very cold Winters and hot Summers. I have my choice of an unfinished basement or unfinished attic to build my home office/music studio. Which space will be less of a hassle regarding temperature and humidity control? Here's some details about each space...

Basement: Brick walls with no opening windows. Floor is lumpy/wavy from hydrostatic pressure but seems to stay dry. There is HVAC vents in the ceiling. Would need to level an area of floor, put in flooring, and frame out walls. Plenty of space.

Attic: Triangular space with exposed insulation and joists. It has a window that opens, but there is no HVAC vents coming up to this floor, so would need a mini-split or window AC unit. Not a ton of space to work with, and a proper drywall job would reduce it a bit more and remove some of the charm of the old exposed wood.

Which space would be more energy efficient overall?

Comment: Will need to check if the attic floor is built to hold weight, some are, some just strong enough to hold a person.  Attics hot in the summer, basements cooler in the summer.  Seems to stay dry and will stay dry are usually two very different ideas, that change after finishing.

Comment: Using attic as living space reduces its ability to act as insulation space. Mine is several feet deep in insulation; that's one of the single highest payback energy saving changes you can make (along with air-sealing)

Comment: Waste heat from equipment and humans creates some amount of background heating for free. It’s not so easy to get free background cooling when it’s too hot to open a window.

Comment: "I'm curious about your opinions" is the _very definition_ of an opinion-based question which is off-topic. Disappointed that this hasn't been closed after 6 hours and that someone provided an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

##### Basement

- More space than the attic
- Already has HVAC, though you may need to make some adjustments
- Because it is in the ground, it will not need as much heating (ground temperature generally is above outside air temperature when it gets really cold) or air conditioning (heat rises) as the attic

The only big concern I see is water. So even though you do not currently have any issues with water, you may want to consider the *possibility* of water problems when it comes to choosing flooring materials. I'm typing this in my basement in the half of it that just has a bare concrete floor, and that works for me. (The other half has carpet, and fortunately the water issues (from internal plumbing and other problems, not external) have all been confined to the concrete area.)

Comment: But the OP generally likes the attic better. It's a difference of opinion which is why we don't allow opinion based questions here.

Comment: @FreeMan There is an opinion factor. I am stating specific factual reasons. I was actually a little surprised to see it wasn't already closed (or even 1 vote for closing at the time I put in my answer) so I answered based on what I consider to be the facts involved.